# Uniformity of Logos Between Sites

Tags: discussion, design, logo

I noticed this today about the logos between the 4 sites.  They all vary in size.  Server Fault's logo is 250x48, Super User's logo is 250x60, and the logos for Stack Overflow and Meta are 250x61.  I understand attempting to maximize efficiency, and the sheer number of times you serve the logo is pretty huge, but if the dimensions of the CSS are the same between the sites, why not try to make the logos the same dimensions as well?

All that really needs to be done is pad Server Fault's logo 13 pixels at the top, and 1 pixel at the top of Super User's logo.  I suspect that the size difference would be almost unnoticeable increasing Super User's logo size, and only somewhat noticeable by increasing Server Fault's.

So, my question is this:  Is there any real reason not to make the logos between the sites all a uniform size?

Comment: Does this actually cause any problems?

Comment: I want to unread this. Give me my time back.

Comment: TRQ: Who cares?

Comment: This is stupid, and approaching google-level style restrictions. "I think a 2px border would be nicer than a 3px one", "Really? Can I see a 10 page usage report to back up your recommendation?" http://www.itpro.co.uk/610294/designer-quits-google-over-data-focus

Comment: Why not also ask Google why they've gone an added padding around search results? Looks like 10px more on either side now.

Comment: Back before some of you were born, I used to get requests like "Shift these print fields by a character", and they really annoyed me, particularly when using the main part of COBOL and not the Report Writer.  If Jeff wants to ignore this, he has my sympathy.

Comment: Weird, I thought this kind of small niceties would be the main point of distinguishing between real successful websites and clones thereof. :) http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/07/code-its-trivial.html

Answer (score 4):

## DIY

- [image: serverfault] (1.84 kB, was 1.69 kB)
- [image: superuser] (3.13 kB, was 3.00 kB)
- [image: stackoverflow] (unchanged, for reference)
- [image: meta] (unchanged, for reference)

---

Yes, but what have I accomplished? Pretty much nothing.

- OMG! Differently sized text!
- WTF! The "p" in "superuser" screws up the baseline between the logos!
- BBQ! Needs more ligature! m&a ﬆackoverﬂow!
- LOL! Needs more <s>unicorns!</s> cowbell!

The reality here is that there is a real tradeoff between these "niceties" and time spent implementing them *and* additional cost in terms of bandwidth and loading time. A hundred bytes on sites like superuser or serverfault [add up faster than you would expect](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/FavIconicoCanBeABandwidthHog.aspx).

Comment: Yes, & is a ligature for 'et'.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ligature_(typography)#Symbols_originating_as_ligatures

Answer (score 3):

I think the bigger question is: Is there any real reason TO make the logos a uniform size? Are there instances where the logos are messing up the layout of the site?

If not, I do not see an issue here.

Comment: Other than colors, the logos are the only design aspect that have a visible difference between the four sites.  If everything else in the template is exactly the same, then why not make the logos the same dimensions?  I realize that this is an extremely minor thing, but it's something I noticed today and wanted to gather some opinions on.

Answer (score 0):

They are all different sites.  I say let Jeff do what he wants.

Comment: I'm not telling Jeff to do anything.  Obviously he is free to do whatever the hell he likes, and whatever he thinks is best for the sites.  However, outside perspectives are useful as an outsider can sometimes see something that an insider wouldn't notice.  And I'm just offering an outside opinion.  Isn't this what this site is for, making suggestions for the sites?

Comment: True, at best though, I think this would be low on the priority list.