# What are the guidelines or constraints for proposed Logos for Area51 sites?

Tags: discussion, area-51, logo

When we propose new Logos on our Beta sites - what are the constraints on it? Maximum dimensions, colors, etc? There must be *some* limits, but the only closely relevant Questions I have found([Uniformity of Logos](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12088/uniformity-of-logos-between-sites), [Who designs the Logos?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52268/who-designs-the-logos-for-area-51-proposals)) have no details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a *tad bit* early for us to provide a an accurate answer. Jin, [our resident awesome designer](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/our-designer-in-residence-jin-yang/), is in the process of mocking up the basic layout that will brand each of our sites. It's simply too early to say how the logo will fit into a design-in-progress.

In the meantime, I would suggest focusing more on logo *ideas* and basic design concepts rather than a finished sample. If the *idea* is good, it can be morphed/squeezed/reworked into something that fits the criteria.