# All Stack Exchange sites logo size

Tags: discussion, support

While browsing the [Stack Exchange page containing all sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#), I've noticed that not all logos have the same size. Is there a direct correlation between the number of users and the logo size? If so, is this based on actual data?

I'm simply wondering about the logic behind the logo sizes and if there's any  reason for it, like the number of users or questions.

[image]

Comment: You might have gotten that visual representation right, yes.

Comment: Probably related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12088/uniformity-of-logos-between-sites?rq=1

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ nope, not at all. This one here is about the size in the grid view of sites list in stackexchange.com, the other one is about the actual site logo, as used on the site itself.